# join columns into one single dataframe using one line of pandas command

Tags: python, pandas

I have 33 single columns, each works as a dataframe:

col1_df, col2_df, col3_df....col33_df

How do I join them together into one single dataframe?

my code is

```
df = [col1_df, col2_df....col33_df], but the return is not a dataframe
```

Is there one pandas line to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

flat the origin df to a list, and concat or merge the col_df

```py
col_df_list = df.values.flatten()
dfn = pd.concat(col_df_list)
```

Comment: Each column is a df at this point, col1 is a df, col2 is a df, col3 is also a df. I want a larger df that combines col1, col2, col3 together. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can use `pd.concat(col_list, axis=1)`, If you can provide some demo data, It will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([col1_df, col2_df, col3_df....col33_df], axis=1)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Would give the desired output.